# how to receive value from implicit intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I am showing a calendar event activity(Android system activity) in my application. I generate it with a "show event detail" button. When I click the button it will show the calendar event activity provided by the Android system. When I modify a value from the event activity, it's reflected in the events table in the Android device, but when I modify the event via my app how do I get a modified value from it?

```
    Intent l_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    l_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    //l_intent.putExtra("calendar_id", m_selectedCalendarId);  //this doesn't work
    l_intent.putExtra("title", "roman10 calendar tutorial test");
    l_intent.putExtra("description", "This is a simple test for calendar api");
    l_intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "@home");
    l_intent.putExtra("beginTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
    l_intent.putExtra("endTime", System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800*1000);
    l_intent.putExtra("allDay", 0);
    //status: 0~ tentative; 1~ confirmed; 2~ canceled
    l_intent.putExtra("eventStatus", 1);
    //0~ default; 1~ confidential; 2~ private; 3~ public
    l_intent.putExtra("visibility", 0);
    //0~ opaque, no timing conflict is allowed; 1~ transparency, allow overlap of scheduling
    l_intent.putExtra("transparency", 0);
    //0~ false; 1~ true
    l_intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
    try {
        startActivity(l_intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, no compatible calendar is found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351563/getting-data-from-an-implicit-intent). This is exactly what you want.

Comment: Kabir121 thanks for technical support. I have one more clarification.  I can not pass Reminder value through implicit intent. how to pass it and i have five reminder for single event.how to do that. we can add five reminder in android calendar event.how to implement it. give your valuable inputs?