# create a custom android browser that open a url that other apps request

Tags: android, url, browser, sharing

I want to write a simple custom `Android` browser, like the `Firefox` and `Chrome` browsers that can be open a specific `URL` when other app choose my custom browser. For example, a mail app want to open a `URL` by sharing and then the user choose my custom browser. Or another android app runs this:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); startActivity(i);
```

But how do my custom browser get the `URL` that passed from the other application?

Comment: The article here describe what I want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351563/getting-data-from-an-implicit-intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear, but if you're talking about handling intents sent from other apps to open the URL in webview [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) tutorial on android developers training explains it pretty well.

Comment: this is a good start as I want the general method to get the url and most text does not cover it. I still need to find where the url is stored in that intent.

Comment: It is quite hard to understand but the training documentation is very good.

Comment: My intention is to make a simple fast browser  for just one url. Not like chrome and firefox which will open unclosed past tabs, which will be very slow for some old devices.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this using intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```